# Would replacing one side of the Dynamic Clock Box with an image be easy or a complete rewrite?

Tags: graphics3d, textures

I've been looking at the code and reading other questions.  I don't know where to start.  Here is the code from the Wolfram example with the addition of importing and resizing an image in the first two lines.  I also changed one of the coords elements to {0.5, 0.5, 0.5}.

```
pablo = WebImage[
   "https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Pablo_Picasso#/media/\
File:Pablo_picasso_1.jpg"];
pablo1 = ImageTake[pablo, {101, 500}, {201, 600}];

vtc = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}};
coords = {{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, {{0.5, 0.5, 
     0.5}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}, {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 
     0}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}}, {{1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 
     1, 1}}, {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}, {{0, 0, 
     1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}};
DynamicModule[{}, 
 Graphics3D[{Dynamic[Texture[clock], UpdateInterval -> 1], 
   Polygon[coords, VertexTextureCoordinates -> Table[vtc, {6}]]}, 
  Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed -> False], 
 Initialization :> (clock := 
    Module[{hour, min, sec, ht, mt, st}, {hour, min, sec} = 
      Take[DateList[], -3]; 
     ht = Pi/2 - 2 \[Pi] hour/12 - (2 \[Pi]) min/720; 
     mt = Pi/2 - 2 \[Pi] min/60; st = Pi/2 - 2 \[Pi] Floor[sec]/60; 
     Graphics[{Thick, Arrowheads[Large], 
       Arrow[{{0, 0}, 0.6 {Cos[ht], Sin[ht]}}], 
       Arrow[{{0, 0}, 0.9 {Cos[mt], Sin[mt]}}], PointSize[Large], 
       Table[Point[0.9 {Cos[i], Sin[i]}], {i, 0, 2 Pi, \[Pi]/6}], 
       Point[{0, 0}], Circle[], Red, 
       Line[{{0, 0}, 0.85 {Cos[st], Sin[st]}}]}]])]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
...
Graphics3D[{
  {Texture[pablo1], 
   Polygon[First@coords, VertexTextureCoordinates -> vtc]},
  {Dynamic[Texture[clock], UpdateInterval -> 1], 
   Polygon[Rest@coords, VertexTextureCoordinates -> Table[vtc, {5}]]
   }}, Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed -> False
 ]
...
```

[image]

Comment: Yes.   I'm glad I didn't try a rewrite!